# Issue with fetchin data from Realtime Database in React js

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have some issue with fetching the data from firebase live database.

The datastructure which i want to fetch looks like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/761lz.png)

Here is my sample code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { getDatabase, ref, set, onValue } from "firebase/database";


import { db } from "../utils/firebase";


const ClientDetailLive = (props) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const { userID } = useParams();
  const { eventID } = useParams();
  const { participantID } = useParams();

  const [event, setEvent] = useState([]);
  const [participant, setParticipants] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
   
 const dbRef = ref(
      db,
      "myPath"
    );

    onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val();
      console.log(data);
      setEvent(data);

  }, []);

    return (
    <>
      Client stuff: {JSON.stringify(params)}
      <h1></h1>
      UserID: {userID}
      <h1></h1>
      Event: {eventID}
      <h1></h1>
      Participant: {participantID}
      <div key={event.id}>
 
        <h2>Event Name: {event.Title}</h2>
        <h2>Datum: {Date(event.Time)}</h2>
       
      </div>{" "}
      <h1>"Ihre Daten"</h1>     

     <h2>Name: {event.Particpants[0].Name}</h2>
    
    </>

  );
};

export default ClientDetailLive;
```

Everything works like expected, the only issue Iam facing is, whenever iam accessing the "Participants" i get follwoing error:

```
ClientDetailLive.js:85 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at ClientDetailLive (ClientDetailLive.js:85:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

Thank you in advance.

I would expect that the participant name will be shown on the display. Since the data exists and is not undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize `event` with `[]` here:

```
const [event, setEvent] = useState([]);
```

But then you use it in the rendering code with:

```
<h2>Name: {event.Particpants[0].Name}</h2>
```

Since you initialize `event` with `[]`, it doesn't have a `Particpants` property and there's no `[0]` on it.

You'll want to ensure that `event` has a non-empty `Participants` array before rendering it. Something like:

```
<h2>Name: {event.Participants && event.Participants.length ? event.Participants[0].Name : "Loading..."}</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 

If I use for example 

{event.Participants?.map((participant) => (
        <div>
          <p>{participant.Name}</p>
          <p>{String(participant.IsComing)}</p>
        </div>
      ))}

I get the proper output, with all the names in the array and their status IsComming.

But if I use your code snippet, i get only Loading... on the screen.

Thank you very much :)